# Wrapping an application/pdf file in ruby File

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am interacting with an external API that sends a PDF file(header content-type as application/pdf)

When I log the response I get something like (snippet)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Feb 2015 12:42:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.20 OpenSSL/0.9.8r PHP/5.2.17
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Label2.pdf"
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: public
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.3
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 330>>
stream
xmQËNÃ0¼÷+æl½ëWÒ[Q[ {K\)UiERàù¤DÂÈ3»Ù<YÑ]ñÁB¾Á<o®5éÞ3)A^àæñP    r·È·
ë^Qê¡âöRdKÖâýã{ÆìåèÜNR²
b-± É2FðÚ©°ªOÖÅw±kUä¡>¢9Bög%W¦K5±m/«jUõïz¾Ã6bàçM[À¢MÑ©³6%£;Û,,äÔWÌ"Z÷H&B¤ymû¡ac)ÕpÜ¨áO7Ñhª  fÓgÌÊúXë¯cyØ#ÁSv5å>rêÎe¼õ[¾í.\£JT|'.$|ú9/I»a§­ä·ÑÆ'$¹@±áÉ~³mF»7u¾tá/G¶
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica-BoldOblique
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Type /Font
/BaseFont /Helvetica
/Subtype /Type1
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding

....

    ^í½ P×ú-¾ßË¿¬Ê«T¥RVÊÒÿ(çÙ«1ñçÕðÄ2)j  3ÌTD@QAÁ   pQEDEAPDAB5oíýÇÃÌo.UÛSMÛ½{Ø«×·¾ÝÝ»Ù_­O>J'þútë~ÚÆ¡>«LÍæý¢'QèÜSßµ·ù¼_üÖX¬ß|üRâÝG×Êþ,­"?|øø¿?}üôét®
3´2ÐÞ4|yÃ:5Ou=w5L=T0­ç®nà¥®ï®®ã¢6Í{°S¨^èfÉöcg¯Î-ÈzWñ*8ôácQ
ÔTQêoÖ$¿¥û¯µÒ÷P×sS? <:.ÿÀD
\Ôt%ê_â®¥t]Õô]{Ìéa¼j§ß¾ÔØ+§¿Ê¯úÀkV  |B©øôB«´m8Vª#éÞÈHS_Dù® VqåÆ¥EÇ¥ç$÷~¨3 Ú6vpÒÅ¯¾.U'cdQOE©/Ö!Ä¿ï*ÞØ/Ñ@EÒôÂùäÌ)
¢9=¡LÒ¨çÁõì7ï!!:!\DÔ;òðéÝú¢^
¥`ÉTh´ü¬IÍP=uò Q
QÁ¢Âkoõ"«£Þ³yà
í<@#UÔk]´=9yÒÖ³;mQj¢ ÕQ¡¢¡Ç«À±ó£¬7ì[¨ñ ½äbÚ[IRU*Jµ­F ís     Ä¡/\d

.....
```

My question is how can I wrap this response in a ruby File object, so that I can upload the pdf to an external storage service like S3?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are logging contains both the *header* and PDF file itself in the *body*.

I'd just save that into a temp file:

```
f = Tempfile.open("/tmp/response.pdf") do |fh|
    response.body # or the method to get the body from your response object
  end
```

and then upload your file `f` to your favorite cloud service.

Comment: Im not sure the whole response is the PDF file. I updated the post the more of the raw output

Comment: The response *body* is the pdf.

Comment: In deed. The file starts exactly at this line: ``%PDF-1.3``. The first part is the *HEADER*. Which library are you using to make the HTTP call? Something like ``response.body`` would be necessary